# Having an XML xlink in my page causes a JS error - TypeError... ...is not a function

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I'm integrating a widget into my page (Houzz). It works, but only if I remove all xlinks in my SVGs. If there are any xlinks, I get the error:

> TypeError: elem.className.split is not a function

The SVG is:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_4_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="1309.016px" height="634.008px" viewBox="0 0 1309.016 634.008" enable-background="new 0 0 1309.016 634.008"
 xml:space="preserve" class="js-animate" style="max-width: 100%;">

  <a xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/meet-the-team"></a>

</svg>
```

The script is:

```
(function(d,s,id){if(!d.getElementById(id)){var js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.async=true;js.src="//platform.houzz.com/js/widgets.js?"+(new Date().getTime());var ss=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];ss.parentNode.insertBefore(js,ss);}})(document,"script","houzzwidget-js");
```

I've created a fiddle, but that's displaying different behaviour - I have to remove the width / height from the svg to make the widget work:
https://jsfiddle.net/v0fkr8jx/

My test page:
http://uprightconstruction.co.uk/index2

Here's the Houzz script being referenced. The error is around line 16 going by Firebug:

```
window.hzmr = window.hzmr || []; window.hzmr.push("widgets:2406");
(function() {
function createIFrame(width, height) {
    var iframeElem = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframeElem.setAttribute("scrolling","no");
    iframeElem.allowTransparency = true;
    iframeElem.border = 0;
    iframeElem.frameBorder = 0;
    iframeElem.style.border = 'none';
    iframeElem.width = width;
    iframeElem.height = height;
    return iframeElem;
}

function containsClassName(elem, className) {
    var classNames = elem.className.split(' ');
    for(var i=0; i<classNames.length; i++) {
        if(className == classNames[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function cleanLocale(locale) {
    var knownLocales = {"en-us":true,"en-gb":true,"en-au":true,"de-de":true,"fr-fr":true,"ru-ru":true,"ja-jp":true,"it-it":true,"es-es":true,"da-dk":true,"nb-no":true,"fi-fi":true,"sv-se":true,"en-ie":true,"en-nz":true,"en-sg":true,"en-in":true};
    if(locale && locale.toLowerCase() in knownLocales) {
        return locale.toLowerCase();
    }
    return 'en-us';
}

function processWidgets(domId) {
    var links = [];
    if(typeof domId == 'string') {
        if(domId.charAt(0) == '#') {
            domId = domId.substr(1);
        }
        var elem = document.getElementById(domId);
        if(elem) {
            links.push(elem);
        }
    } else if(typeof domId != 'undefined' && ('nodeName' in domId)) {
        links.push(domId);
    } else {
        links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    }
    var pid = new Date().getTime() + '' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
    var houzzLinks = [];
    var houzzReviews = [];
    for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if(containsClassName(links[i],'houzz-share-button')) {
            houzzLinks.push(links[i]);
        } else if(containsClassName(links[i], 'houzz-review-widget')) {
            houzzReviews.push(links[i]);
        }               
    }
    for (var i=0; i < houzzReviews.length; i++) {
        var review = houzzReviews[i];
        var pro = review.getAttribute('data-pro');
        var mini = review.getAttribute('data-size');
        mini = (mini == 'mini');
        var locale = cleanLocale(review.getAttribute('data-locale'));
        var iframeWidth = mini?225:300;
        var iframeHeight = mini?130:435;

        if(pro) {
            var reviewUrls = {"en-us":"http:\/\/www.houzz.com\/reviewWidget","en-gb":"http:\/\/www.houzz.co.uk\/reviewWidget","en-au":"http:\/\/www.houzz.com.au\/reviewWidget","de-de":"http:\/\/www.houzz.de\/reviewWidget","fr-fr":"http:\/\/www.houzz.fr\/reviewWidget","ru-ru":"http:\/\/www.houzz.ru\/reviewWidget","ja-jp":"http:\/\/www.houzz.jp\/reviewWidget","it-it":"http:\/\/www.houzz.it\/reviewWidget","es-es":"http:\/\/www.houzz.es\/reviewWidget","da-dk":"http:\/\/www.houzz.dk\/reviewWidget","nb-no":"http:\/\/www.houzz.no\/reviewWidget","fi-fi":"http:\/\/www.houzz.fi\/reviewWidget","sv-se":"http:\/\/www.houzz.se\/reviewWidget","en-ie":"http:\/\/www.houzz.ie\/reviewWidget","en-nz":"http:\/\/www.houzz.co.nz\/reviewWidget","en-sg":"http:\/\/www.houzz.com.sg\/reviewWidget","en-in":"http:\/\/www.houzz.in\/reviewWidget"};
            var iframeSrc = reviewUrls[locale] + '/' + encodeURIComponent(pro) + '/' + (mini?'mini':'');
            var iframeElem = createIFrame(iframeWidth, iframeHeight);
            review.parentNode.replaceChild(iframeElem, review);
            iframeElem.src = iframeSrc;
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i < houzzLinks.length; i++) {
        var link = houzzLinks[i];

        var imageURL = link.getAttribute('data-img');
        var linkURL = link.getAttribute('data-url');
        var title = link.getAttribute('data-title');
        var showCount = link.getAttribute('data-showcount') == '1';
        var hzID = link.getAttribute('data-hzid');
        var whiteBg = link.getAttribute('data-whitebg');
        var format = link.getAttribute('data-format');
        var locale = cleanLocale(link.getAttribute('data-locale'));
        var identifier = i + '' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
        link.id = 'hzbtn' + identifier;
        var referer = document.location.href;

        var buttonWidths = {"en-us":52,"en-gb":52,"en-au":52,"de-de":75,"fr-fr":88,"ru-ru":52,"ja-jp":52,"it-it":52,"es-es":52,"da-dk":52,"nb-no":52,"fi-fi":52,"sv-se":52,"en-ie":52,"en-nz":52,"en-sg":52,"en-in":52};
        var buttonWidth = buttonWidths[locale];

        var buttonUrls = {"en-us":"http:\/\/www.houzz.com\/buttonWidget","en-gb":"http:\/\/www.houzz.co.uk\/buttonWidget","en-au":"http:\/\/www.houzz.com.au\/buttonWidget","de-de":"http:\/\/www.houzz.de\/buttonWidget","fr-fr":"http:\/\/www.houzz.fr\/buttonWidget","ru-ru":"http:\/\/www.houzz.ru\/buttonWidget","ja-jp":"http:\/\/www.houzz.jp\/buttonWidget","it-it":"http:\/\/www.houzz.it\/buttonWidget","es-es":"http:\/\/www.houzz.es\/buttonWidget","da-dk":"http:\/\/www.houzz.dk\/buttonWidget","nb-no":"http:\/\/www.houzz.no\/buttonWidget","fi-fi":"http:\/\/www.houzz.fi\/buttonWidget","sv-se":"http:\/\/www.houzz.se\/buttonWidget","en-ie":"http:\/\/www.houzz.ie\/buttonWidget","en-nz":"http:\/\/www.houzz.co.nz\/buttonWidget","en-sg":"http:\/\/www.houzz.com.sg\/buttonWidget","en-in":"http:\/\/www.houzz.in\/buttonWidget"};

        var iframeSrc = buttonUrls[locale] + '?url=' 
            + encodeURIComponent(linkURL);
        if(imageURL) {
            iframeSrc += '&img=' + encodeURIComponent(imageURL);
        }
        if(title) {
            iframeSrc += '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
        }
        if(showCount) {
            iframeSrc += '&count=1';
        }
        if(whiteBg) {
            var whiteBgValue = 0;
            if(String(whiteBg) == '1' || whiteBg.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
                whiteBgValue = 2;
            } else if(String(whiteBg) == '0' || whiteBg.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
                whiteBgValue = 1;
            }
            iframeSrc += '&whiteBg=' + encodeURIComponent(whiteBgValue);
        }
        if(hzID) {
            iframeSrc += '&hzid=' + encodeURIComponent(hzID);
        }
        iframeSrc += '&locale=' + encodeURIComponent(locale);
        iframeSrc += '&ref=' + encodeURIComponent(referer);
        iframeSrc += '&pid=' + encodeURIComponent(pid);

        if(format == 'custom') {
            if(link.getAttribute('data-loaded') == '1') { continue; }
            iframeSrc += '&fmt=' + encodeURIComponent(format);
            iframeSrc += '&domid=' + encodeURIComponent(identifier);
            var extElem = document.createElement('script');
            extElem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
            extElem.id = 'hzjs' + encodeURIComponent(identifier);
            extElem.src = iframeSrc;
            link.parentNode.appendChild(extElem);
        } else {
            var iframeElem = createIFrame(buttonWidth + (showCount?57:0), 20);
            link.parentNode.replaceChild(iframeElem, link);
            iframeElem.src = iframeSrc;
        }
    }
}

window.houzz = window.houzz || {};
window.houzz.processWidgets = processWidgets;
processWidgets();
})();
```

Any ideas about what's causing this?

Comment: When I see createElement in something SVG related that's almost always a mistake. Don't you need to use createElementNS (with the SVG namespace)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the script you are loading is getting all elements named `a`. 
This will take [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and [SVG `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) elements without distinction.

The problem is that for SVG elements, the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/class) attribute or `className` property is animatable. Which means that when you call `a.className`, you'll get an [SVGAnimatedString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString) Object, composed of two strings in two keys : `baseVal` and `animVal`.
Each of these keys has a `split` method, but not the SVGAnimatedString itself.

So the code should be modified to either find out if this is an HTML `<a>` (by checking its `namespaceURI` property), or to check if the `split` method is available before calling it, or by calling `elem.getAttribute('class')` instead of `elem.className`.